# Colon in C# List definition

Tags: c#, json.net

I have to deserialize an JSON object array that contains a colon in root object name.

Does anyone know if I can achieve this somehow with colon in list definition?

```
public List<Customers> ngcp:customers { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

No, the proper way to do this would be to specify the name using an attribute or other method supported by json.net.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ngcp:customers")]
public List<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
```

[image: LINQPad example]

Comment: Thanks, could you please help me with that object collection of ngcp:customers? 
I'd like to get every object in that collection and use it for datagrid:

Comment: http://www.felferhuette.at/box/public.php?service=files&t=5b1816ae1db36ce362abcbad45fec1fd